# Not able to resolve InputSurface and OutputSurface in EncodeDecodeTest

Tags: android, mp4

I am trying to convert mp4 file in to low frame rate and low resolution video for this i am trying to use an example from bigflake.com. But when I copied a EncodeDecodeTest class then it is not able to resolve InputSurface and OutputSurface class. I googled but do not find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find this classes in right here:

OutputSurface.java https://goo.gl/rlJbkR

InputSurface.java https://goo.gl/uvcqO2

Also you will need to create

TextureRender.java https://goo.gl/I9XyFs